# Nginx auth for rewrite to an other domain

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to set up an authentication to a rewrite to an other domain in my nginx configuration for downloading csv files.

Basic example:
If somebody enters http://example.com/foo/bar.csv the pop up windows should appear and after entering correct credentials, the file from http://newdomain.com/downloads/bar.csv should be downloaded.

What i have in my nginx.conf:

```
location ^~ /foo  {
    auth_basic "AUTH";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/auth/foo;

    rewrite (?i)^\/foo\/(.*\.csv)$ https://newdomain.com/downloads/$1 permanent;
}
```

The pop up window appears if i enter something like /foo/test but if i enter /foo/test.csv it downloads directly the csv file without asking the credentials.

Does somebody know how i can authenticate correctly for a rewrite to an external page?

Comment: Have you tried removing the permanent property and trying in an incognito session?

Comment: yes, without success. I ran it everytime in incognito session and also reloading nginx